# Is it possible to replace python import command?

Tags: python

I have a strange requirement. I can't install (or compile) python-fabric module on machine (at workplace). I was wondering Is it possible to copy the entire source code of fabric as single file and paste into a my file (something like "sqlite amalgamation") ? Does that work ?

-> Get the source of fabric module. 
-> Copy all files content of this module in to file (singlefile.py)
-> Now import this singlefile.py on my myfile.py

Any thoughts?  (Lets assume, the dependencies like paramiko,pycrypto already available on workplace).

Comment: If a module needs to be _compiled_, as in with a C compiler, then this will definitely not work. But I thought Fabric was pure-Python, so I'm not sure why ypu're having this problem.

Comment: Why not include it into the structure of your program?

Comment: No; you **cannot** replace statements.

Comment: You *can* however use ``__import__``, or the ``importlib`` or ``imp`` libraries.

Comment: I don't think he's really trying to replace the `import` command, despite the title of the question.

Comment: But meanwhile, you definitely _can_ replace statements. Changing the syntax is hard, but changing the semantics is pretty easy with an import hook and an AST transformer. See [MacroPy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy) for a great example. (Of course using an import hook to replace the semantics of `import` would be a little meta, but no harder than anything else.)

Comment: Do you just want to use this library locally on your machine, like in a virtual environment or something?

Comment: If you do manage a workaround, this restriction will do nothing other than make more work for you while providing no security, stability, or other benefit. The right answer for this problem is to discuss your project requirements with your workplace's IT department.

Comment: What can and can't you do at your workplace? Install globally? Install locally? Have folders with python files in them? Move files around in your home directory / around the script? Do anything other than run your single file? Each of these questions will change the answer.

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I'm not sure whether I understood your question. You want to try python 'include' instead of 'import' stmt? I don't know what 'include' does.
will read about it.
TigerhawkT3: yes, i think that's the risk to take for messing up with import :)
Makoto: yes its clustered environment.(commerical  storage nodes) which doesn't have access to other repos. 
cge: I can't reach outside world other than our servers. I don't have access to change server repos. I can move files with in system (as root).

Comment: @lakshmipathi: I think the "include" is like the C preprocessor: it just incorporates the text of the included file into the file currently being compiled. This allows C to fake having modules; it also allows clever people to write projects like sqlite3 that can be compiled either as a bunch of separate files or as one giant file; it also is half the main reason make exists and is a pain in everyone's neck.

Comment: It's not a risk, it's a certainty: if you can't get work done under your workplace's IT policy, the only truly effective solution is to communicate with the authoritative parties (IT and your manager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library has any C extensions, there is definitely no way to do this.

If not, it's *technically* possible, but practically not.

What you almost certainly want to do is use a `virtualenv`, or, if you can't do that, a user site-packages instead of a system site-packages, or some other way to get around the "can't install" problem, and just install it.

---

But if you're interested in the technical bits…

If Fabric were, say, a single `.py` file, that would be easy. But looking at [the source](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/tree/master/fabric), it's got a lot of files. And they're organized in a hierarchy, not just a flat directory. And there's a non-trivial `setup.py`, which usually means the way it ends up installed isn't the same way it is in the source tree.

So, to make this work, what you'd need to do is:

- Do a "development" install into the source tree.
- Take each file that gets installed, and wrap its source up in a giant string (first backslash-escaping any triple-quotes); followed by a function that `compiles` that string, `exec`s it in a new globals dict, builds a `types.ModuleType` object out of that `dict`, and inserts it into the `sys.modules` dict; followed by a call to that function.
- Concatenate the wrapped files in order of a reverse topological sort by which file imports which.
- Embed the result at the top of your file.

The only really tricky, as opposed to tedious, bits here are:

- Modules are first-class objects, with a type with a normal constructor and everything.
- `import spam` always looks for `sys.modules['spam']` before turning to the module loader, so if you pre-populate that, `import` will just accept it

In theory, that ought to work. Or something close to it; I may have missed a detail. In practice, I sincerely doubt you want to do that.

Comment: Thanks abarnert for the detailed answer! But yes, it looks like really tedious task to do. I really doubt, I can do this task :p